# What minifigs are these three?

Tags: minifigure-identification

[image]

[image]

[image]

Could you help identifying these 3 minifigures?

Answer (score 5):

First one is [loc111 "Sykor"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=loc111) from the Legends of Chima line, albeit with a different helmet (I'm guessing [part 30171 "aviator cap"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30171) in black):

[image: sykor]
[image: aviator cap]

---

Second one is [col186 "Prospector"](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?M=col186) from series 12 collectible minifigures, albeit with a red scarf ([part 30133](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30133&idColor=5)) instead of beard, and different head (part [3626cpb0798 "Head Male White and Gray Bushy Eyebrows"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3626cpb0798)) and hair (part [62810 "Hair short tousled"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=62810), I guess?).

[image: prospector]
[image: red scarf]
[image: head]
[image: hair]

---

Third one is [tlm046 "RoboSWAT with helmet"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=tlm046), which appears in three sets in the [Lego Movie line](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=S&catString=804):

[image: roboswat with helmet]